# How to fix NOT NULL error (error code: 1064)?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, where-clause, sqlyog

I cant figure out what is the problem below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test0`(
    $qsFilter       VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
SELECT
    cs.Customer_First_Name
FROM customer_subscriptions cs
WHERE 1=1 AND ($qsFilter IS NULL OR cs.Customer_First_Name = $qsFilter)
END$$
```

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a semicolon, but I would write this as:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test0`(
    in_qsFilter       VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT cs.Customer_First_Name
    FROM customer_subscriptions cs
    WHERE 1 = 1 AND
          (in_qsFilter IS NULL OR cs.Customer_First_Name = in_qsFilter);
END$$
```